# My if-then-else-end statement is failing in Lua; how can I fix it?

Tags: lua, syntax-error, awesome-wm

I'm trying to improve my `rc.lua` for the [Awesome window manager](http://awesome.naquadah.org/). The default `rc.lua` sets up a menu with the following code:

```
myawesomemenu = {
   { "manual", terminal .. " -e man awesome" },
   { "edit config", editor_cmd .. " " .. awesome.conffile },
   { "restart", awesome.restart },
   { "quit", awesome.quit }
}
```

I use Awesome as the window manager for the GNOME desktop environment, so I want to have Awesome use the `gnome-session-quit` program instead of `awesome.quit`, but only if the environment variable "DE" is set to "gnome". Therefore, I replaced the fifth line with

```
{ "quit", if os.getenv("DE") == "gnome" then os.execute("/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit") else awesome.quit end }
```

But when I reload the file, I get "unexpected symbol near if". How can I fix this, and what causes it?

Comment: Cause: In Lua, an `if` statement is not an expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ "quit", (os.getenv("DE") == "gnome") and function() os.execute("/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit") end or awesome.quit}
```

`a and b or c` is like the C expression `a ? b : c`, provided that `b` is not `false`.

Comment: The `os.execute("/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit")` part probably needs to be wrapped into a function. Otherwise it ends up executing right where it is instead of later.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure Lua doesn't work like that :P

Have you tried wrapping it in a function?

```
{
    "quit", 
    function()
        if os.getenv("DE") == "gnome" then
            os.execute("/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit")
        else
            awesome.quit
        end
    end
}
```

Can you also try rewriting `awesome.quit` instead?

```
_awesome_quit = awesome.quit
awesome.quit = function()
    if os.getenv("DE") == "gnome" then
        os.execute("/usr/bin/gnome-session-quit")
    else
        _awesome_quit()
    end
end
```